# ARM asm equ array length

Tags: arrays, assembly, armv7

I'm again trying to do something relatively simple in x86 NASM syntax but I'm having a horrible time finding anything about it in ARM.  I'm trying to get the length of a static array so that I have something to compare against in a loop.

[This](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Caccddic.html) nicely shows that equ is like a #define statement in c but that still doesn't really help me find the length of a static array.

In x86 NASM you'd do this:

```
SECTION .data
    brownFox:       db "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!", 10, 0
    brownFox_bytes: equ $-brownFox
```

In ARM I would assume that there's something similar but I really can't seem to find anything about this.  I tried doing this:

```
.C.0.1569:
    .word 0
    .word 1
    .word 2
    .word 3
    .align 2
@ other stuff like .LC0-2 and main
.L4:    .align 2
.L3:
    .word   .LC0
    .word   .LC1
    .word   .LC2
    .word   .C.0.1569
    .equ    len, $-.L3+16
```

But that obviously fails as this isn't NASM on x86.

If it helps I'm using Qemu emulating an ARMv7 system running Debian linking with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somewhat confused about which toolchain you are using. You link the manual for the *ARM compiler toolchain* but then mention `gcc` and also your file seems to be gnu syntax. I'll stick with `gnu` for the time being, and please clarify your question if that's not the case.

In gnu `as`, the current location symbol is not `$` but `.`. As such, the original `nasm` example can be rewritten as:

```
.data
brownFox: .string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!\n"
.equ brownFox_bytes, .-brownFox
```

Similarly for your word data, I just can't figure out what you really wanted there.

PS: you can find the [gnu as manual online here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html).

Comment: ah, well I'm in an assembly class and we did the entire term in x86 asm but now we're expected to go learn ARM asm for the last assignment all on our own and I'm having trouble figuring out what's what.  I'm using gcc so I suppose that means that I'm using gnu suntax.  The link was because I don't know what I'm doing and it said ARM at the top.